# How to dump LLVM IR after each middle-end pass?

Tags: debugging, compiler-construction, clang, llvm

I can add option **-print-after-all** to **llc** to dump IR and MIR after each back-end pass, but middle-end phase seems have no such convenient option.

Answer (score 0):

It's there! `opt -O2 -print-after-all file.ll` will do it.

Use `opt` instead of `llc` to run middle-end passes instead of back-end passes, and you can use `--help-hidden` to see the secret flags.